# Script that lists all file names in a folder, along with some text after each name, into a txt file

Tags: bash

I need to create a file that lists all the files in a folder into a text file, along with a comma and the number 15 after. For example

My folder has `video.mp4, video2.mp4, picture1.jpg, picture2.jpg, picture3.png`

I need the text file to read as follows:

```
video.mp4,15
video2.mp4,15
picture1.jpg,15
picture2.jpg,15
picture3.png,15
```

No spaces, just `filename.ext,15` on each line. I am using a raspberry pi. I am aware that the command `ls > filename.txt` would put all the file names into a folder, but how would I get a ,15 after every line?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

***bash*** *one-liner*:

```
for f in *; do echo "$f,15" >> filename.txt; done
```

---

To avoid opening the output file on each iteration you may redirect the entire output with `> filename.txt`:

```
for f in *; do echo "$f,15"; done > filename.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(ls folder_name); do 
   echo $i",15" >> filename.txt; 
done
```

It's possible to do this in one line, however, if you want to create a script, consider code readability in the long run.

#### Edit 1: better solution

As @CristianRamon-Cortes suggested in the comments below, you should not rely on the output of `ls` because of the problems explained in this discussion: [why not parse ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls). As such, here's how you should write the script instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd folder_name 
for i in *; do 
   echo $i",15" >> filename.txt; 
done
```

You can skip the part `cd folder_name` if you are already in the folder.

#### Edit 2: Enhanced solution:

As suggested by @kusalananda, you'd better do the redirection after done to avoid opening the file in each iteration of the for loop, so the script will look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd folder_name 
for i in *; do 
   echo $i",15"; 
done >  filename.txt
```

Comment: When using `bash` you should not rely on the `ls` output. See @RomanPerekhrest answer instead.

Comment: @CristianRamon-Cortes why is that? do you have an example?

Comment: Well the basic problem is that UNIX allows almost any character as a filename, including for example spaces, new lines, tabs, etc. So when parsing the ls output you could split the filename. You can find an extended and precise information here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls

Comment: you could update your answer providing the `for i in *;` solution too so that is more complete than the other ones.

Comment: @CristianRamon-Cortes Thanks for the suggestion and the link.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ printf '%s,15\n' *
picture1.jpg,15
picture2.jpg,15
picture3.png,15
video.mp4,15
video2.mp4,15
```

This will work if those are the only files in the directory.  The format specifier `%s,15\n` will be applied to each of `printf`'s arguments (the names in the current directory) and they will be outputted with `,15` appended (and a newline).

If there are other files, then the following would work too, regardless of whether there are files called like this or not:

```
$ printf '%s,15\n' video.mp4  video2.mp4  picture1.jpg  picture2.jpg  "whatever this is"
video.mp4,15
video2.mp4,15
picture1.jpg,15
picture2.jpg,15
whatever this is,15
```

Or, on all MP4, PNG and JPEG files:

```
$ printf '%s,15\n' *.mp4 *.jpg *.png
video.mp4,15
video2.mp4,15
picture1.jpg,15
picture2.jpg,15
picture3.png,15
```

Then redirect this to a file with `printf ...as above... >output.txt`.

If you're using Bash, then this will not make use of any external utility, as `printf` is built into the shell.

Answer (score 0):

A solution without a loop:

```
ls | xargs -i echo {},15 > filename.txt
```

Comment: Space was added _after_ the comma, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Just 1 command line using 2 `msr` commands recusively (`-r`) search specific files:

`msr -rp your-dir1,dir2,dirN -l -f "\.(mp4|jpg|png)$" -PAC | msr -t .+ -o '$0,15' -PIC > save-file.txt`

- If you want to sort by time, add `--wt` to first command like: `msr --wt -l -rp your-dirs`
- Sort by size? Add `--sz` but only the prior one is effective if use both `--sz` and `--wt`.
- If you want to exclude some directory, add like: `--nd "^(test|garbage)$"`
- remove  tail `\r\n` in `save-file.txt` : `msr -p save-file.txt -S -t "\s+$" -o "" -R`

See `msr.exe` / `msr.gcc48` etc in my open project https://github.com/qualiu/msr `tools` directory.